# Express JS not rendering jade template

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I'm going to keep this short, I'm just trying to render a jade template using express js.
I'm using express 3.0.0rc5 and jade 0.27.6.

Here's my jade templates, the layout:

```
// test-layout.jade
doctype 5
html
  head
    title My title
    block head
  body
    #content
      block content
```

And the index:

```
// test-index.jade
extends test-layout

block head
  script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js")

block content
  h1 My page
```

Here's some excerpts from app.js:

```
var app = express();
// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get('/test-jade', function(req, res) {
    res.render('test-index', {}, function(err, html) {
    });
  });
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('this works');
});
```

Now whenever I try to go to http://myurl.com/test-jade the browser just hangs and timesout without showing any output in the console (even though I'm in dev mode).

However when I go to http://myurl.com/test I see 'this works'.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here, I'm currently upgrading from 2.5 to 3.0.

Thanks in advance if anyone has advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it the blank call back?

```
 res.render('test-index', {}, function(err, html) {
 });
```

In my app I'm using

```
res.render('test-index', {});
```

Comment: Adding a comment for anyone who finds this in the future.  I had a similar problem and just putting

    res.render('test-index', {})

Didn't fix it.  I had to use the callback method to write the data.

Comment: `res.render('test-index')` is `test-index` relative to anything?